# Subsetting dates from a data frame--> getting NA when changing format to DATE

Tags: r

I am trying to subset some days and a certain distance (<5) from the following data set

```
nest_ID bn_ID Tag_ID      date       time            dateR RSSI distance
1      39   519     38  23/03/2016 00:03:51 23/03/2016 00:03  -20 61.74631
```

For some reason when I try to change the format of the date: to date I got a column full of NA, so I cant subset my data
(I am using `lubridate` and `dplyr`)

```
Nestbox.39$date <- as.Date(Nestbox.39$date, format = "%d%/m%/Y%")

M <- Nestbox.39[Nestbox.39$date > as.Date("19/04/2016") & Nestbox.39$distance <= 39, ]
```

And then I get this

```
 nest_ID bn_ID Tag_ID cntr date time dateR RSSI distance 
NA        NA    NA     NA   NA <NA> <NA>  <NA>   NA       NA
```

I would really appreciate all your help; I am not sure what is going wrong with my subsetting...But its clear that something is really wrong! =)
Thank you a lot!
Mara

Comment: Ya sorry typing mistake.. but still NAs.....The problem is not there..

Comment: Now you have `format = "%d%/m%/Y%"`. Note the `%d%/m` which should read `%d/%m`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use base **R** or the package `lubridate`:

1) Base **R**:

```
Nestbox.39$date <- as.Date(Nestbox.39$date,format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

2) lubdridate:

```
library(lubridate)
Nestbox.39$date <- dmy(Nestbox.39$date)
```